# Building an R package that uses the GSL on Windows

Tags: r, windows, gsl

I have little to no knowledge about developing for Windows. I have written an R package that works just fine on Linux. I am trying to get it to work on Windows. Unfortunately, I feel I just hit a wall. The package uses the GSL library. The first thing I did was to compile it using mingw-w64, which worked as expected. I then proceeded to build the package. Everything went fine up until when R tests if the package can be loaded. I get this error message:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
  impossible de charger l'objet partagé 'C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/r_packages/Bayes.mix.biv.reg/libs/x64/Bayes.mix.biv.reg.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

The french part could be translated to something like "unable to load the shared object".

I don't understand why this is failing. Here is the line that produced the dll:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o Bayes.mix.biv.reg.dll tmp.def DICWAIC.o Utils.o wrapperV11.o wrapperV11woallocations.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64 -LC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64 -lR
```

where `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` is from Rtools. How can Bayes.mix.biv.reg.dll not be a valid Win32 application?

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the *example package* included with RcppGSL, even if don't plan on using Rcpp or RcppGSL.

It has this in [its src/Makevars.win](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppgsl/blob/master/inst/examples/RcppGSLExample/src/Makevars.win)

```
## This assumes that the LIB_GSL variable points to working GSL libraries
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I$(LIB_GSL)/include
PKG_LIBS=-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

The key here, as with some other packages is that you *really, really* want to rely on the prebuilt libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I was basically using the same Makevars. I'm gonna give a try to prebuilt libraries.

Comment: The same is used by a number of other package ... because we can assume "by convention" that the CRAN Windows builds machines have `LIB_GSL` set.  You can download that library and test locally too, with proper env.vars.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but where can I get proper prebuilt binaries?  The only one I found were compiled for Visual Studio Community and don't play well with mingw-64.

Comment: No, no, no---not VS. They hang somewhere off CRAN.

Comment: Could be better documented but I think [this is what you want](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/ThirdPartySoftware.html). I used this in the past (but I rarely work on Windows these days...).

Comment: Leading to [this page](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/libs.html).