# R package build failing on Windows machines (AppVeyor) due to missing GSL - GNU Scientific Library

Tags: r, windows, package, gsl, appveyor

I am developing an R package called `DescObs` (https://github.com/MaaniBeigy/DescObs). It imports `conf.limits.nct` function from `MBESS`,  which itself depends on another package called `gsl`. It shows no problems at all for `R CMD check` and the installation of `DescObs` on Linux machines assessed by `Travis` continuous integration platform (https://travis-ci.org/MaaniBeigy/DescObs). However, `AppVeyor` [fails](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/MaaniBeigy/descobs):

```
** libs
*** arch - i386
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"c:/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c airy.c -o airy.o
airy.c:1:29: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf_airy.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gsl/gsl_sf_airy.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [c:/R/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: airy.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gsl'
* removing 'c:/RLibrary/gsl'
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package 'gsl' had non-zero exit status
Calls: <Anonymous> ... with_rprofile_user -> with_envvar -> force -> force -> i.p
Execution halted
Command exited with code 1
```

I also tried the solution recommended in [Building an R package that uses the GSL on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536015/building-an-r-package-that-uses-the-gsl-on-windows) but it did not help. I also compiled it using `mingw-w64` and `gcc-4.6.3`, which both showed the same error.
Moreover, I tried to install by `- cmd: vcpkg install gsl:x64-windows`, but did show the same error. Here, you can see my [appveyor.yml](https://github.com/MaaniBeigy/DescObs/blob/master/appveyor.yml).
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, my previous [appveyor.yml](https://github.com/MaaniBeigy/DescObs/blob/master/appveyor.yml) could finally build it:

```
install:
  - ps: Bootstrap
  - cmd: git submodule update --init --recursive
  - cmd: git clone https://github.com/CxxTest/cxxtest
  - cmd: cd c:\tools\vcpkg
  - cmd: vcpkg integrate install
  - cmd: vcpkg install gsl:x64-windows
  - cmd: vcpkg install fftw3:x64-windows
  - cmd: cd "%APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%"
environment:
  global:
    USE_RTOOLS: true
    NOT_CRAN: true
    _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS: true
    _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_: true
    #R_CHECK_ARGS: "--run-dontrun"
  matrix:

  - R_VERSION: devel
    R_ARCH: x64
    GCC_PATH: gcc-4.6.3
```

I do not know the exact reason, but I am glad it [works](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/MaaniBeigy/descobs).

**edit: I faced the problem again in another [package](https://github.com/MaaniBeigy/cvcqv)**. This line by [Owen McDonnell](https://github.com/OwenMcDonnell) `image: previous visual studio 2015` could solve the [problem](https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/24752-r-package-build-fails-due-to-the-error-cannot-find-definition-for-package-gsl). Refer to [cvcqv package](https://github.com/MaaniBeigy/cvcqv/blob/master/appveyor.yml) for the full `appveyor.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this thread because I faced what I think is a very similar situation when I tried to update the package `gsl`:

> - installing *source* package 'gsl' ...
>   ** package 'gsl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** using staged installation
>
>   **********************************************    WARNING: this
>   package has a configure script
>   It probably needs manual configuration    **********************************************
>
> ** libs "C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include         -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c airy.c -o airy.o airy.c:1:10: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf_airy.h: No such file or
> directory  #include <gsl/gsl_sf_airy.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:238: airy.o] Error 1 ERROR:
> compilation failed for package 'gsl'
>
> - removing 'C:/Users/shima/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/gsl'
> - restoring previous 'C:/Users/shima/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/gsl' Warning in
>   install.packages :   installation of package ‘gsl’ had non-zero exit
>   status

This thread helped me find the solution, a warm thank you, along with [this discussion](https://github.com/RobinHankin/gsl/issues/2) and [this one](https://github.com/r-windows/docs/blob/master/rtools40.md#readme)
For those of you on `Windows`, using `Rtools`, here are my steps to solve this issue, i.e. not being able to update `gsl` package in `R` under `windows`:

1. start `Rtools Bash` (found in `apps`, `Rtools 4.0` in the `Windows` menu)
2. Run `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gsl` and confirm with yes (`y`)
3. I don't think it's relevant, but i ran `pacman -Syu` just before to update my `Rtools` and throwing the command `pacman -Sl` gave me the correct name of the package for the `pacman` command in 2.

Updating `gsl` in `Rstudio` now leads to a clean

- DONE (gsl)